# unbounded series of positive numbers. is $1/a_n \to 0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

$a_n$ is an unbounded series of positive numbers. Prove or disapprove:
$$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \frac1{a_n}  = 0$$

I think this is true but I don't succeed to prove it

Comment: This is not clear.  What's an unblocked sequence? And the nature of the limit you are taking is not clear.

Comment: What have you tried to do so far? Also, I'd like to know the answer to Lulu's question.

Comment: Do you mean unbounded?

Comment: Trusting that the edit is what you intended, and that "unblocked" means "unbounded" then the answer is, in general, no.  Consider the sequence where $a_{2n}=2n$ but $a_{2n+1}=1$.  But perhaps you meant something else.

Comment: it should be bottomLimit and not just limit

Comment: What I imagine you mean by "bottomLimit" is more properly called $\liminf$.

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  People here (including me) keep trying to guess what you are asking but why make your readers guess?  The most recent edit is guessing that you meant the $\liminf$ which is also what I guessed in my posted solution.  However, you objected that you meant something else.  If you did mean something else, please say what it is.  "Bottom Limit" is not a standard phrase....what do you mean by it?

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: suppose the sequence is 
$$
1, \text{something}, 1, \text{something}, 1, \text{something}, \ldots .
$$

Answer (score 0):

For positive, unbounded sequences the desired claim (regarding the $\liminf$) is true.

Indeed, let $n_i$ be a subset of the indices such that $$\forall i\;a_{n_i}<a_{n_{i+1}}\quad  \& \quad \lim_{i\to \infty} a_{n_i}=\infty$$

Then the $\lim_{i\to \infty}\frac 1{a_{n_i}}=0$ which tells us that $\liminf_{n\to \infty}\frac 1{a_n}≤0$ but since all the terms are positive we must have $\liminf_{n\to \infty}\frac 1{a_n}≥0$ so we are done.

Comment: thanks, but the question is about bottomLimit

Comment: But what does "bottom Limit" mean?  I assumed you meant the [Limit Inferior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_superior_and_limit_inferior).  that is to say, the least upper bound of the set of real numbers less than all the $\frac 1{a_n}$.